# CMake - Build still succeeded even without the frameworks to be included

Tags: ios, frameworks, cmake

I downloaded the project of [minicap-ios](https://github.com/damonsong/ios-minicap) and planned to play with it and study CMake at the same time. The project will be compiled with CMake after executing ./build.sh.

**Here is the content of build.sh:**

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../
make
```

**Here is the content of the CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.2)
project(ios_minicap)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x -Wall -g")

set(SOURCE_FILES
        src/minicap.cpp
        src/SimpleServer.cpp src/SimpleServer.hpp
        src/FrameListener.cpp src/FrameListener.hpp
        src/Banner.cpp src/Banner.hpp
        src/JpegEncoder.cpp src/JpegEncoder.hpp
        src/StreamClient.mm src/StreamClient.h
        src/Frame.hpp)

add_executable(ios_minicap ${SOURCE_FILES})

include_directories(
        /usr/local/opt/jpeg-turbo/include
)

target_link_libraries (ios_minicap
        "-framework Foundation"
        "-framework CoreFoundation"
        "-framework CoreMedia"
        "-framework CoreVideo"
        "-framework CoreMediaIO"
        "-framework AVFoundation"
        /usr/local/opt/jpeg-turbo/lib/libturbojpeg.a)
```

As can be seen, some iOS frameworks are used in here. So when building the project, I would expect that CMake will go look for the frameworks needed by the project.

I tried building the project with all requirements set. The building goes successful. You can also see the path of the required frameworks:

[image]

**Then I tried removing those frameworks, reran build.sh. Here's what I got:**

[image]

Now, the frameworks were not included in the building process I guess. But what confuses me is that the building still succeeded with no error. Why is that so?